# Possible scenario to get GPS Coordinates Immediately

Tags: android, gps, locationlistener

In the scenario of `GPS` is truned ON for last 10 mins but no client intiated any request. After some time if we can made a request using **getLastLocation()** (Without using LocationListener). Will I get location coordinates immediately or `GPS` takes some time to pinpoint location, **If so how much time will it take?**

Comment: How are we supposed to tell you that? I guess it depends on many factors that you can't predict. From my experience getting the location can happen in less than a second up to more than a minute.

Comment: Sometimes, the GPS fix will take forever, because the device is not in position to receive GPS signals (e.g., underground parking garage).